# compile ncurses --disable-database why “_nc_fallback” undefined

Tags: android, c, ncurses

```
./configure --prefix=$TMUXTARGET --without-database --with-fallbacks=xterm-256color,vt100 --without-xterm-new --disable-home-terminfo --with-termlib --enable-termcap --disable-database

In [205]: !make V=1
cd man && make DESTDIR="" RPATH_LIST="/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/local/lib" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/ncurses-6.2/man'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/ncurses-6.2/man'
cd include && make DESTDIR="" RPATH_LIST="/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/local/lib" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/ncurses-6.2/include'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/ncurses-6.2/include'
cd ncurses && make DESTDIR="" RPATH_LIST="/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/local/lib" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/ncurses-6.2/ncurses'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/ncurses-6.2/ncurses'
cd progs && make DESTDIR="" RPATH_LIST="/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/local/lib" all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/ncurses-6.2/progs'
gcc ../objects/infocmp.o ../objects/dump_entry.o -L../lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../progs -I. -I../include -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -DNDEBUG -O2 --param max-inline-insns-single=1200 -L../lib  -lncurses -ltinfo    -o infocmp
../lib/libtinfo.a(lib_setup.o): In function `_nc_setupterm':
lib_setup.c:(.text+0x924): undefined reference to `_nc_fallback'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:284: recipe for target 'infocmp' failed
make[1]: *** [infocmp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/qgb/work/tmux-static/ncurses-6.2/progs'
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to compile ncurses without terminfo

I want to build static application run on Android shell ,thers is no terminfo

normal build ncurses would get err `can't find terminfo`

Comment: works for me (on Debian).   See [bug reporting](https://invisible-island.net/personal/bug-reports.html) guidelines, and [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#problems_building).

Comment: @Thomas Dickey  what is your debian , gcc , ncurses source version ?

Answer (score 1):

The example in the question is incomplete because it does not show the failure to build the `ncurses/fallback.c` file.  For example, if an empty file was created, then running "make" again will have nothing to do (i.e., an empty object file results from an empty source file).

The [`--with-fallbacks`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/INSTALL.html#option:with-fallbacks) option assumes that you have

- the infocmp program
- a terminfo database

The section of [**`INSTALL`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/INSTALL.html) (in the ncurses sources) [*`CONFIGURING FALLBACK ENTRIES`*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/INSTALL.html#CONFIGURING-FALLBACK-ENTRIES) goes into some detail explaining this.  If you are building ncurses on a system which does not have both of these, and want to use the fallback feature, you must do this:

- build ncurses without the fallback feature, installing that to a temporary directory, and
- rebuild ncurses (including reconfiguring), using the infocmp and terminal database from the first build to generate the source needed for the fallback feature.